# Python 3.8 encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.8

Recently, using Python 3.8, I ran into encoding issue.  I simplified the issue to a few lines of code.  Maybe someone from the Python community could throw some light on the behavior I see:

```
import os, sys
c = chr(146)            # character hex 92 dec 146, end quote mark in cp1252
a = "Don" + c + "t"     # Don't with end quote instead of apostrophe
ae = a.encode('cp1252', errors='replace')
print(ae)
print(a)
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='cp1252')
print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
b'Don?t'
Dont
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/1data/DEV/MyPy/Test/test_e1.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(a)
  File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
```

So, since the \x92 is a valid character in "cp1252", why is \x92 replaced by '?' in first line of output.
If I did not use errors="replace" it would raise an exception.
Why, printing to standard out with "cp1252" raises an exception when printing to standard out with 'utf-8' doesn't?

Comment: Your terminal does not support cp1252, that's really all there is to it. You prove it by being able to print UTF-8 encoded strings. You can only set one encoding to a terminal.

Comment: Python3 strings are composed of unicode codepoints, not character set byte values: `ord(b'\x92'.decode('cp1252'))` -> `8217`, which is the codepoint of 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'

Comment: I am running this on Windows so cp1252 is definitely supported.  The output is from terminal in Visual Studio Code.  The CMD terminal show the same behavior.

Comment: Is there a way in Python to deal with strings like in "C", with single byte character?  Is Python 2.x like that?

Comment: Python2 is more like that, but it sounds as if you want to work with bytes rather than str?  `bs = b'Don' + b'\x92' + b't'` -> `b'Don\x92t'`; `bs.decode('cp1252')` -> `'Don’t'`

Answer (score 2):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode : *Sixty-five code points (U+0000–U+001F and U+007F–U+009F) are reserved as control codes, and correspond to the C0 and C1 control codes defined in ISO/IEC 6429. U+0009 (Tab), U+000A (Line Feed), and U+000D (Carriage Return) are widely used in Unicode-encoded texts. In practice the C1 code points are often improperly-translated (Mojibake) legacy Windows-1252 characters used by some English and Western European texts with Windows technologies.* So chr(146) in Unicode does **not** represent the `’` character.

To get the `’` character in a Python3 (Unicode) string you could either:

- convert from `bytes` type: `b'Don\x92t'.decode('cp1252')`
- find the correct Unicode codepoint for `’`, which is 8217 dec or 2019 hex : `'Don\u2019t'`
- just type the character: `'Don’t'` - Python3 accepts unicode characters in source files

Comment: Yes Python 3 accepts Unicode characters in source files, but you may need a special encoding comment to tell it how your source file is encoded.

Comment: @MarkRansom isn't UTF-8 the default now, in lack of `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` string? I vaguely recall seeing that somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure, but even if it is there's no guarantee the source was *saved* as UTF-8.  Especially given the details of the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom true.

Comment: I thank you all for your input.  For me (new to Python due extra of time because of quarantine) it's hard to deal with strings other than bytes.

Comment: @ChristopherB. that's probably the most controversial feature of Python 3.  Strings are always Unicode and you have to be aware of encoding to know how that translates to/from bytes.